# Testing Dropwizard Resource's POST method

Tags: post, jersey, resources, dropwizard

Hello I have the following resource class

```
@Path("/api")
@Api("My API")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public class MyResource {


  public MyResource() {
   // assign some values in teh constructor
  }


  @POST
  @Timed
  @UnitOfWork
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @ApiOperation(
      value = "",
      response = Response.class)
  @ApiResponses(
      value = {@ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Method not allowed"), @ApiResponse(code = 400,
          message = "some custom mesage")})
  public Response createMyObject(MyObject o, @Context UriInfo uriInfo)
      throws JsonProcessingException {
}
```

And I am trying to unit test it using this

```
@Test
  public void testCreate() throws JsonProcessingException {


    Entity<?> entity = Entity.entity(myObjInstance, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    final Response response = resources.target("/api").request().post(entity);
}
```

This gives me a 404, I have verified that the resource is correctly registered. Also the GET methods in this resource work as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add the rest of your test harness? In particular where you register the resource with the test framework.